# Is there any utility or built in class in NHibernate that force a class to load it without lazy in a special situation?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lazy-loading

I have an web application that uses NHibernate as ORM. I enable lazy loading for my classes but I want to load some classes without lazy in a special situation.

Now is there any utility or built in class in NHibernate that force a class to load it without lazy in a special situation?

Note: I don't want to remove lazy property in my mapping file, because I use lazy loading in some of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you are using the ICriteria Api to specify your queries, you can use `SetFetchmode` to specify eager loading for some of the properties on a per-query basis.

I did a blog post [on wrapping the behavior in a query object](http://jwbs-blog.blogspot.com/2009/08/wrapping-nhibernate-fetchmode.html), it may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking at your system in different light.

http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Making-Roles-Explicit-Udi-Dahan