# Eager Fetching with nhibernate Criteria API

Tags: c#, nhibernate, eager-loading

I am trying to use the criteria Api over multiple tables with eager loading.

My stripped-down Entities look like this:

```
class Limit
{
    Risk {get; set;}
}

class Risk
{
   List<Company> Companies { get;set;}
}

class Company
{
  List<Address> OldAdresses {get;set;}
}

class Address
{
  string Street { get;set;}
}
```

My Criteria call looks like this:

```
var CriterionGruppe = Expression.Eq("Account.Id", someGuid);

var temp = _transaktion.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Limit))
.SetFetchMode("Risk", FetchMode.Eager)
.SetFetchMode("Risk.Companies", FetchMode.Eager)
.Add(CriterionGruppe)
.SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
.List<Limit>();
```

The addresses are still loaded with many Selects. How can I include the old adresses of a Company in my criteria call.

I already read a blog entry in ayende's blog and several other question here at stackoverflow. But still had no luck.

I hope someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance peter

[When must we use eager loading in NHibernate? What is it's usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989058/when-must-we-use-eager-loading-in-nhibernate-what-is-its-usage)

[NHibernate Eager Fetching Over Multiple Levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332703/nhibernate-eager-fetching-over-multiple-levels)

[Ayende Blog](http://ayende.com/blog/4367/eagerly-loading-entity-associations-efficiently-with-nhibernate)

Answer (score 8):

```
var account = _transaktion.Session.Load<Account>(someGuid);
var temp = _transaktion.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Limit))
    .SetFetchMode("Risk", FetchMode.Eager)
    .SetFetchMode("Risk.Companies", FetchMode.Eager)
    .SetFetchMode("Company.OldAddresses", FetchMode.Eager)
    .Add(Expression.Eq("Account", account))
    .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
    .List<Limit>();
```

However this is very inefficient. You are loading a massive amount of duplicate data to make 1 sql query. A better approach would be

1. load a projection of what is actually needed
2. use Futures and Batched lazy loading to avoid a single cartesian result set and select n+1.

Comment: Thank you. That are the hints I was hoping for. I knew that it wasn't very efficient the way I queried.